# Position of elements

Tags: haskell

the function should give me the position of the searched elements.

e. : index 'b' "dfbhjbd" -> [3,6]

I've got so far:

index b (x:xs) = length ( takeWhile ( /= b)  xs )

but takeWhile will immediately stop after finding the matching elements. so following elements  will be left out.

i tried something like this:

```
index b (x:xs) = length ( tak b  xs )
 where 
  tak b [] = []
  tak b xs 
        | b /= x == x:tak b xs
        | otherwise = [], tak b xs
```

Beside being unable to run the code because of parse error, it would not show the right results.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've already seen the problem with `takeWhile` - I can understand why you tried this (after all you want to use `length`) but maybe you should try to find a solution where you don't have to use `length` in the first place.

A good approach might be to keep track of the indizes while you traverse the input list and then look out for the elements equal to `b

---

if you want to use recursion then you can go all the way:

```
index :: (Eq a, Num t) => a -> [a] -> [t]
index b xs = index' 1 xs
  where
    index' _ [] = []
    index' i (x:xs)
      | b == x = i : index' (i+1) xs
      | otherwise = index' (i+1) xs
```

example

```
λ> index 'b' "dfbhjbd"
[3,6]
```

as you can see I'm using a inner function here that takes care of the indizes and the recursion

---

another approach would be to use `zip` to get pairs of indizes and elements and then use `filter` and `map` to get the results out:

this corresponds to what you tried earlier

```
index :: (Eq a, Num t, Enum t) => a -> [a] -> [t]
index b xs =
  map fst . filter ((== b) . snd) $ zip [1..] xs
```

Comment: Thank you. i do not quite understand how the filter is working. why do i get just the numbers and not e.g (1,g)?

Comment: this is not the filter - it's the very first function `map fst` - `fst` (for *first*) will give you the first part of a 2-tuple: `fst (x,y) = x` and `map` applies this function to all elements in the filtered list

Comment: no need - it's not easy to see if you are not used to this style of writing down your stuff